# Raster map doesn't work correct after 3.1 version

Tags: here-api

I'm updated Maps API for JavaScript to 3.1v. After that Raster map doesn't show correctly. After some zooms getting not a clear picture and problems with the font. Actual:

I've tried to put some different pixel ratio and another map types but it didn't help. Is there a bug?

This is how I init map:

````
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
            'apikey': apiKey,
        });

 $scope.defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
            tileSize: pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
            ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320,
            pois: true
        });
        $scope.geocoder = platform.getGeocodingService();

        $scope.map = new H.Map(
            document.getElementById("here-map-canvas"),
            $scope.defaultLayers.raster.normal.map,
            {
                zoom: 12,
                center: { lat: officeLat, lng: officeLng }
            });

        $scope.markerGroup = new H.map.Group();

        $scope.map.addObject($scope.markerGroup);



        var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents($scope.map));                                                    //Step 3: make the map interactive

        $scope.ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault($scope.map, $scope.defaultLayers);    ```

**Please check imgs:**

Actual: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu17g.jpg
Expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tcid8.jpg



<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
Refs:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css?dp-version=1549984893" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core-legacy.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service-legacy.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **pixelRatio** parameter next to **zoom** & **center**:

```
$scope.map = new H.Map(
    document.getElementById("here-map-canvas"),
    $scope.defaultLayers.raster.normal.map,
    {
        zoom: 12,
        center: { lat: officeLat, lng: officeLng },
        pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
    }
);
```

and disable fractional zoom on **Behavior** as well as **ZoomControl** UI (which is enabled by default in v3.1):

```
behavior.disable(H.mapevents.Behavior.Feature.FRACTIONAL_ZOOM);

$scope.ui.removeControl('zoom');
$scope.ui.addControl('zoom', new H.ui.ZoomControl({
  fractionalZoom: false,
  alignment: H.ui.LayoutAlignment.RIGHT_BOTTOM
}));
```

For more details see documentation for map options: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-options.html#h-map-options

ZoomControl Options:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-ui-zoomcontrol-options.html

and Features to be disabled on Behavior: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-mapevents-behavior-feature.html

Comment: Didn't help, I tried this before. This problem occurred after update to 3.1 libraries.

Comment: If tiles get blurry after some zooming operations, the problem is most probably the fractional zoom which was introduced in version 3.1. 
I updated my answer and added disabling fractional zoom. This should help.

Comment: Thanks for that. It helped for zooming but the image is still not clear.

Comment: Can you provide screenshot and the code sample again? Or better jsfiddle link so I can test  by myself?

Answer (score 0):

Please add below libraries and try to run it, also share the libraries that has been used in the code.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,
width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"
type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core-legacy.js"
type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"
type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service-legacy.js"
type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the response. I already have these links and it doesn't work. I libraries which I use to the description.